# Apply RenderTransform to an EllipseGeometry

Tags: c#, wpf, rendertransform

I'm looking to apply the contents of a RenderTransform to the physical properties of an EllipseGeometry, meaning that the Center/RadiusX/RadiusY properties of the EllipseGeometry are changed by the application of the transform.  My reason for doing this is, I have a drawing program in which you can draw ellipses and after drawing you are allowed to scale/rotate/translate the ellipse, which under the hood I apply as RenderTransforms on the original Path object (whose "Data" property is an EllipseGeometry object).  Now currently, for other geometries in my drawing program (bezier curves, lines, arcs, etc) I use the following approach to apply the RenderTransforms when it comes time to save the data to a file.

```
    Geometry clone = linePath.Data.Clone();
    clone.Transform = linePath.RenderTransform(); //Which is a TransformGroup in my case
    Geometry transformedGeometry = clone.GetFlattenedPathGeometry();
```

This leaves me with a clean geometry onto which the RenderTransform of the "linePath" has been applied.  Now I can easily save the contents of this geometry to a file in "Mini Syntax" and reload it at a later time.  I know I can use the same approach for an EllipseGeometry, but the result is an approximated PathGeometry describing the translated EllipseGeometry and I don't know of a way of converting that result back into an EllipseGeometry when I reload the data from a file.  Currently, for the EllipseGeometry objects in a drawing I save the physical properties (Center/Radius/etc) and then save the corresponding RenderTransform as a XAML string to file.  Then on load I just create the EllipseGeometry from the properties and apply the saved RenderTransform.

Now, this approach works, but I feel it would be cleaner to save the translated ellipse geometry as I do in the case of other geometries.  I also have uses elsewhere in my application for applying RenderTransforms as physical transformations to EllipseGeometries and the workarounds are getting uglier and uglier, so I'd like to nail down a process for doing this (if it is even possible).

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**
Just to make the question a little more open, I'm not committed to using EllipseGeometry, since I don't see how it could possibly be used to describe all of the different transformations that can be present in a RenderTransform (i.e. Rotate).  So if there is some other way or some other geometry that could be used that provides "ellipse-like" behavior, I'd definitely be interested in hearing about it.